# General solution to the dirac equation expressed as a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-equation, spinors, klein-gordon-equation

For the Klein Gordon Field, the equations of motion are described by the equation

$$(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} + m^2)\phi(\vec{x},t)=0$$

Which when the field is expressed as a Fourier transform of the momentum we can get that
$$(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} + m^2)\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\tilde{\phi}(k,t) e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}}=0$$

Which is the same as

$$\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} + m^2)\tilde{\phi}(k,t) e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}}=0$$

From this we get a differential equation for $\tilde{\phi}$ and we get that
$$\phi(\vec{x},t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 }(a(\vec{p})e^{-ip \cdot x} + a^{\dagger}(\vec{p})e^{-ip \cdot x})$$

For the Dirac field which equations of motion are given by

$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi(x,t) = 0$$

Can we arrive at the form:

$$\psi(\vec{x},t)= \sum_{s} \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}(a_s(\vec{p})u_s(\vec{p})e^{-ip \cdot x} + b_s^{\dagger}(\vec{p}) v_s(\vec{p})e^{ip \cdot x})$$

Using the same technique that we used for the Klein Gordon equation where
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}\tilde{\psi}(k,t)e^{-ik \cdot x}=0$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joshua.  I didn't read through your question line-by-line, but it appears as though you derived an expression for the solution to the Klein-Gordon equation in fairly excruciating detail, and then asked if a similar path can be followed for the Dirac equation.  Note that anybody who is in a position to answer this question already understands your derivation quite intimately, so approximately 95% of the body of your question is unnecessary.

Comment: Since the answer to your question is yes, my suggestion would be to try it and then ask a (succinctly worded) question if you run into conceptual difficulties which may arise when working with spinors.  Otherwise, this is just a very lengthy request for the derivation of the corresponding solution to the Dirac equation, which can be found [all over the internet](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/four.pdf).

Comment: Your last integrand contains $p$ and $k$ at the same time.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski yh sorry that's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But this is very homework-like so I'll only sketch the logic. I hope other answers do the same.

Note that $(i\not\partial+m)(i\not\partial-m)=(\partial^2+m^2)$, almost by definition (this is the whole point of the Dirac equation). Therefore, if $\psi$ satisfies
$$
(i\not\partial-m)\psi=0\tag1
$$
it *also* satisfies
$$
(\partial^2+m^2)\psi=0\tag2
$$
Therefore, you can use *your own derivation* to write
$$
\psi_\alpha(\vec{x},t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 }(a_\alpha(\vec{p})e^{-ip \cdot x} + a_\alpha^{\dagger}(\vec{p})e^{-ip \cdot x})\tag3
$$
where $\alpha=1,2,3,4$ is a spinor index.

Now let us go back to the initial equation and check whether there are any further conditions (as we may have introduced [fictitious solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) by manipulating the equation: the operator $(i\not\partial+m)$ is not invertible so multiplying by it can embiggen the space of solutions).

If we apply $(i\not\partial-m)$ to our solution $(3)$, we get
$$
0=(i\not\partial-m)\psi=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 }(\not p-m)a(\vec{p})e^{-ip \cdot x} + \text{c.c}\tag4
$$
and hence the spinor $a_\alpha$ must satisfy the *algebraic* equation
$$
(\not p-m)a(\vec{p})\equiv0\tag5
$$
But this is easy to solve: let $u_s(\vec p)$, $s=1,2$, be the two linearly-independent vectors that solve this (there are two because this is the rank of the matrix $\not p-m$, as is easily checked by brute force). Then, the general solution to $(5)$ is
$$
a(\vec p)=\sum_{s=1,2}u_s(\vec p)a_s(\vec p)
$$
where $a_1,a_2$ are two $1\times 1$ annihilation operators (as opposed to $a_\alpha$, which is a $4\times1$ spinor).

Thus, finally,
$$
\psi(\vec{x},t)=\sum_{s=1,2}\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 }u_s(\vec p)a_\sigma(\vec p)e^{-ip \cdot x} + \text{c.c}\tag6
$$
as is well-known.

Comment: Hi, I like the logic used here, but there's one step that I'm struggling to justify, why can you assume that each term of the expansion equals 0 when applying the Dirac equation when in general if the sum of terms equals 0 then each term doesn't necessarily have to be 0

Comment: I don't really understand the linear independence argument

Comment: @JoshuaPasa $e^{ipx}$ and $e^{-ipx}$ are linearly independent and therefore $Ae^{ipx}+Be^{-ipx}=0$ implies $A=B=0$.

Comment: is it because if you expand them out as complex numbers you get that the imaginary and real part should be 0 and then it pops out from there?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa If you put $x=0$ you get $A+B=0$ and if first take a derivative and then put $x=0$ you get $A-B=0$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry I have to wait before I can award you the bounty

Comment: @JoshuaPasa You're welcome. We usually encourage users to wait as much as possible before awarding bounties or even accepting answers, in case new, better answers appear. If you award/accept too early, you discourage other users from posting more answers.