# Dirac equation on a superposition

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-equation, superposition, linear-systems

If the following is a solution to the Dirac equation
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)(\psi_1+\psi_2)=0$$
Therefore after distributing
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_1+(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_2=0$$
Can we assume that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ also have to satisfy the dirac equation:
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_1=0$$
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_2=0$$
and if so why can we make this assumption?

This is because I want to find the solution to the equation:
$$\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)[u(k)e^{-ik\cdot x} +v(k)e^{ik\cdot x}]=0$$

Where $k \cdot x$ is the four dot product. I know that If I do distribute it and solve it seperatley it gives me the correct answer

$$\psi(x)= \sum _ s\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}[a_s (k)u_s(k)e^{-ik\cdot x} +b^\dagger_s(k) v_s(k)e^{ik\cdot x}]$$

However I dont know of a rigorous way to prove I can split it up.

--------------------------------------Attempt-----------------------------------------

This is where I have gotten so far. Since
$$\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)[u(k)e^{-ik\cdot x} +v(k)e^{ik\cdot x}]=0$$
We can write
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)[u(k)e^{-ik\cdot x} +v(k)e^{ik\cdot x}]=0$$
splitting it up
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)u(k)e^{-ik\cdot x} + (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m) v(k)e^{ik\cdot x}]=0$$
For this to hold
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)u(k)e^{-ik\cdot x} = G$$
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)v(k)e^{ik\cdot x} = -G$$
Where $G$ is a general function. The only way I can prove $G = 0$ is that if $G=-G$. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: It's true that if both individual spinors satisfy the Dirac equation then so does their sum but the converse is not necessarily true. So we can't make this assumption.

Comment: @SheldonCooper Please don't answer in a comment.  On SE generally answers gain more reputation points than comments (which beyond a certain point gain none) because we want to encourage people to answer properly.  Comments are also not guaranteed to be left in place and can be deleted within warning.

Comment: @SheldonCooper I've updated my answer so the context of the equation is more clear

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605071/2451

Comment: @SheldonCooper What about in the context of the problem im having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what  you  are groping at is that the  functions $e^{ikx}$ and $e^{-ikx}$ are linearly independent. Therefore if  a sum $ae^{ikx}+be^{-ikx}=0$ everywhere you  must have $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Disproval by counterexample: construct functions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ that have the following property
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_1=\psi_3$$
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_2=-\psi_3$$
where $\psi_3$ is a spinor field that is at least $\psi_3(x,t)\not=0$ for one spacetime point $x=x_0, t=t_0$.

Then obviously
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_1+(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi_2=\psi_3-\psi_3=0$$
Therefore, there exist $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ which do not satisfy the Dirac equation, but whose sum satisfies it.